# Random forests with scikit learn .9 or below

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikits, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am having some weird problems installing Scikit learn on my mac and my linux box. Only scikit learn .9 installs.

is there any way to learn random forests using this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random Forests and Extremely Randomized Trees [were both introduced in 0.10](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#changes-0-10). If you are under debian or ubuntu you can try to use the [neurodebian repository](http://neuro.debian.net/) that provides packaged version for scikit-learn (and large bunch of other scientific python tools in their latest versions).

Also can you please report your build issues along with the error messages on the scikit-learn project mailing?

Comment: Wow! Neurodebian made it so easy...I had seen it before, I didn't realize it was a repository; I assumed it was another version of linux...now everything works fine. Thanks a lot!